# Pass level time to Congratulations scene cocos2d

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Just wondered if someone could quickly give me a hand. Im building a simple puzzle slider game, ive added a timer to the game now and all i want to do is pass the time it took to complete the puzzle over to the congrats scene. Could anyone just have a look at my code see where im going wrong please?

play.h

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Box.h"


@interface PlayLayer : CCLayer
{
    int timeInt;
    int secs;
    int mins;
    CCLabel *timeLabel;
    NSString *TotalTimeString;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int timeInt;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int secs;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int mins;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *TotalTimeString;

@end
```

Play.m

```
#import "PlayLayer.h"
#import "Congrats.h"

@implementation PlayLayer
@synthesize timeInt;
@synthesize secs;
@synthesize mins;
@synthesize TotalTimeString;


-(id) init{
    self = [super init];

    TotalTimeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %02d:%02d", mins, secs];
    timeLabel = [[CCLabel labelWithString:TotalTimeString dimensions: CGSizeMake(130,27) alignment: UITextAlignmentCenter fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:25.0] retain];
    timeLabel.position = ccp(155,430);
    [self addChild:timeLabel];

    [self schedule: @selector(tick2:) interval:1.0];


    return self;
}

-(void) tick2: (id) sender{
    timeInt++;
    secs = timeInt % 60;
    mins = timeInt / 60;

    [timeLabel setString: TotalTimeString];

}

-(void) check: (id) sender data: (id) data{
    int valueToCheck = 0;
    bool breakOut = false;
    for (int y=0; y < box.size.height && !breakOut; y++) {
        for (int x=0; x < box.size.width && !breakOut; x++) {

            Tile *tile = [box objectAtX:x Y:y];
            if (tile.check != [box hashOfXY:x y:y]) breakOut = true;
            valueToCheck++;
        }

    }

    int totalTiles = box.size.width * box.size.height;

    if (valueToCheck == totalTiles){
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCFadeTransition transitionWithDuration:1 scene:[Congrats node]]];

        CCScene *scene = [Congrats scene];
        scene.TotalTimeTakenWhenDiedString = TotalTimeString;
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:scene];
    }
}

@end
```

Congrats.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "PlayLayer.h"

@interface Congrats : CCLayer {
    CCLabel *timeLabel;
    NSString *TotalTimeTakenWhenDiedString;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *TotalTimeTakenWhenDiedString;
+(id) scene;

@end
```

Congrats.m

```
#import "Congrats.h"
#import "DifficultyLevel.h"
#import "PlayLayer.h"
#import "PlayLayerMedium.h"
#import "PlayLayerHard.h"
#import "MainMenu.h"


@implementation Congrats

@synthesize TotalTimeTakenWhenDiedString;

+(id) scene {

    // ‘scene’ is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // ‘layer’ is an autorelease object.
    Congrats *layer = [Congrats node];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;

}

// on “init” you need to initialize your instance

-(id) init {

    // always call “super” init

    // Apple recommends to re-assign “self” with the “super” return value

    if( (self=[super init] )) {

        timeLabel = [[CCLabel labelWithString: TotalTimeTakenWhenDiedString dimensions: CGSizeMake(130,27) alignment: UITextAlignmentCenter fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:25.0] retain];
        timeLabel.position = ccp(155,430);

    }
    return self;

}

-(void) goToGameplay: (id) sender {

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCFadeTransition transitionWithDuration:1 scene:[MainMenu node]]];

}


}


@end
```

I was kind of hoping that, that would work. But i keep getting this error "error: request for member 'TotalTimeTakenWhenDiedString' in something not a structure or union"

Anyone help at all?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
CCScene *scene = [Congrats scene];
scene.TotalTimeTakenWhenDiedString = TotalTimeString;
```

The object `scene` is of type `CCScene` and you are trying to access `TotalTimeTakenWhenDiedString` on it. But that is a property of `Congrats`, not of `CCScene`.

---

Here's a suggestion which might work, by getting the `Congrats` object out from `scene`. (Caveat: I'm not familiar with cocos2d, and I only looked it up quickly [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.0/interface_c_c_node.html). This may be a terrible way to be doing it!)

Change here:

```
// add layer as a child to scene
[scene addChild:layer z:0 tag:1]; // tag it with 1
```

and here:

```
CCScene *scene = [Congrats scene];
Congrats *congrats = (Congrats *)[scene getChildByTag:1]; // get the congrats child object, which we tagged 1
congrats.TotalTimeTakenWhenDiedString = TotalTimeString;
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:scene];
```

Comment: Ok so i could use `Congrats *scene = [Congrats scene];
  scene.TotalTimeTakenWhenDiedString = TotalTimeString;
  [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:scene];` But it throws out a warning:"warning: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct Congrats *', expected 'struct CCScene *' when passing argument 1 of 'replaceScene:' from distinct Objective-C type"

Comment: No, you have just confused things more! Notice that `[Congrats scene]` returns an object of type `CCScene`. For you code to work, it would have to return an object of type `Congrats`. I don't understand your code enough to say more.

Comment: I know, im completely new to all this i apologise. All im trying to do is have a countdown timer like in my code above. Then when the puzzle is complete pass the time to congrats.

Comment: I've edited my answer with something that might help. Can you see what I did, and why?

Comment: I see where your coming from, but where does this line go `[scene addChild:layer z:0 tag:1]; // tag it with 1`

Comment: In  `+(id) scene`, where the line is currently `[scene addChild: layer]`.

Comment: Yeh thats removed the error i was getting earlier, thanks for that. Got problems with that timer not working now though, so ill need to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

... Why dont you just create a singleton class which you can use as a global object? and access/update it anywhere in the game?

Comment: Ive only been doing this about a month, so im trying to start basic first.